# PHPWord HTML to Word design issue

Tags: php, phpword

I am using PHPWord library to convert my HTML template to Word.

[Library link](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

My code to convert HTML to Word file is as below:

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $htmlTemplate);
$targetFile = __DIR__ . "/1.docx";
$phpWord->save($targetFile, 'HTML');
```

I am facing below issues:

1. I am applying background color and font color using inline style but font color is only working and background color is not working.

```
 <p style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:#FF0000;">Some text</p>
```

2. I am using below HTML code to allow Page break within sections of HTML templates. but it does not work in exported Word file.

```
<div style="page-break-after:always"><span style="display:none">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

3. I am using span tag to mark some word in bold or change the color of word in paragraph. but when i export to Word file, content after span tag, moves to new line below the word. I tried with **display:inline** css property in span tag. but it doesn't work.

```
<p>some text before span tag <span style="color:#FF0000;display:inline">XXXXX</span> Text after span tag.</p>
```

**Edit:**

Please recommend any other library which i can use to convert HTML with inline css to Word if above mentioned issues can't be resolved with PHPWord!

Comment: As you can see on [Official Page](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html), you can't use background color.

Comment: Styles listed here applies when we are adding content in Word using PHPWord syntax. But i have HTML template which i am converting to word. so i cannot use these styles!

Comment: yes sorry, see [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/4a530d1d97b064b87d9e2a1cc64cab996246569c/src/PhpWord/Shared/Html.php#L418), list of style.

Comment: Yes i seen this file and on debugging, in function parseStyle, when i printed $styles at the end of function before returning, Style properties are printed correctly there. but don't know what wrong happens afterwards and it does not reflect in document

Comment: One point i noted is that background-color is working with <td> tag but not with <div> or <p> tag!

Comment: PHPWord's HTML Reader capabilities seem to be _very_ rudimentary. https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#readers I'd recommend looking at non-PHP convertors --- that you call with `shell_exec` if your process flow is bound with PHP. For example: https://tika.apache.org/ converts all sorts. Otherwise: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+html+to+docx

Comment: is there an ability to import .css file? like <link rel="stylesheet" href="doc-rtf-styles.css">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just performed a very simple test and it is working correctly. My code is pretty much exactly the same as yours except that I'm telling the system to write it as a Word document, not HTML.

```php
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$htmlTemplate = ' <p style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:#FF0000;">Some text</p>';

$phpWord = new PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
Html::addHtml($section, $htmlTemplate);
$targetFile = __DIR__ . "/1.docx";
$phpWord->save($targetFile, 'Word2007');
```

Which produces:

[image: Screenshot showing requested background and foreground text correctly applied in Word document]

If you change the save mode to `HTML`, the background color does disappear, however it isn't a Word document anymore anyways, just raw HTML, so I don't think that matters.

```php
$targetFile = __DIR__ . "/1.html";
$phpWord->save($targetFile, 'HTML');
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! It solved my first and third issue. Still page break is not working in my generated doc. So guide me if you have any idea about that.

Comment: I have solved page-break issue too with some customization in phpword. So no need to look over this issue anymore!!

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of stuffs within a single question/topic. So I'll just base my answers on your enumerated design issues:

## Background color

You may be able to render a background color through [styling a table](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#table) like so:

```php
$table_style = array( 'bgColor' => '#FFFF00' );
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$table = $section->addTable($table_style);
$table->addRow();
$cell = $table->addCell();
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($cell, $htmlTemplate);
```

## Page breaks

The [sample html](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_26_Html.php) from the docs doesn't seem to support page breaks within an html code. However, you may be able to render pagebreaks within the sections by implicitly calling [addPageBreak()](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_03_Sections.php#L17) like so:

```php
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $someHTMLcode);
$section->addPageBreak();
$section->addText("some plain text");
$section->addPageBreak();
```

## Unexpected inline text breaks

Maybe you could try to replace some `spaces` with `&nbsp;` like so:

```html
<p>some text before span tag&nbsp;<span style="color:#FF0000;">XXXXX</span> Text after span tag.</p>
```

I hope some of these -- if not all -- may work for you. Good luck!